# Child Theme, who can point me in the right direction?

Tags: parent-child-theme, theme-fallback

I am working on a website in Magento. I've created a custom design package with a child- and a parenttheme. However, I can't get the child/perenttheme setting to work, despite all the articles (for example [the article by Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml)) I've found on the internet. It seems that Magento doesn't fall back to the parent theme but to the base/default instead. Can this be caused by the fact that I've installed Magento website on a subdomain instead of the maindomain/directory?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your current directory structure and design configuration settings?

If you setup your package name like company and your default theme like website you can have the following fallbacks:

company / website / template etc.

company / default / template etc.

base / default / template etc.

Note that if you use a custom package (company in this case) it doesn't fall back to default / default anymore, a place where a lot of extensions put their template and layout files, you have to copy those to company / default.

For the skin directory you have those fallbacks as well but always make sure the images referenced in the CSS are in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the structure

```
app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme (=child)
app/design/frontend/custompackage/default (=parent)
```

Somehow Magento doesn't fall back on the parent (the default theme in the same package) but falls back to base/default. It seems as if Magento doesn't use the theme.xml file in

```
app/design/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/etc
```

EDIT:

Marco, thank you. I've looked into it and renamed the parent directory to 'default' and copied the css and image files from the parent into the childtheme folder and it seems to have done the trick. Only thing I've noticed is the fact that the logo.png file is pulled from the base/default theme now insted of the child- or parenttheme.